# LESS - Can you chain multiple selectors together to save writing multiple classes?

Tags: less

Instead of writing this:

```
.class-one .class-two h2, .class-one .class-two h3, .class-one .class-two h4,
.different-class-one .different-class-two h2, .different-class-one .different-class-two h3, .different-class-one .different-class-two h4
.another-class-one .another-class-two h2, .another-class-one .another-class-two h3, .another-class-one .another-class-two h4
{
  background-color: @orange;
}
```

Is there a way to define a set of classes as the main selector, then change the final selector?

Something like:

```
.class-one .class-two h2 / h3 / h4,
.different-class-one .different-class-two h2 / h3 / h4,
.another-class-one .another-class-two h2 / h3 / h4
{
  background-color: @orange;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a [mixin](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins):

```css
.header-template() {
    h2, h3, h4 {
        background-color: @orange;
    }
}

.class-one .class-two,
.different-class-one .different-class-two,
.another-class-one .another-class-two {
    .header-template();
}
```

(after declaring the `@orange` variable, the previous compiles to)

```css
.class-one .class-two h2,
.different-class-one .different-class-two h2,
.another-class-one .another-class-two h2,
.class-one .class-two h3,
.different-class-one .different-class-two h3,
.another-class-one .another-class-two h3,
.class-one .class-two h4,
.different-class-one .different-class-two h4,
.another-class-one .another-class-two h4 {
  background-color: #ffa500;
}
```